# same URL for a POST and GET method. How to choose which one when linking to the URL?

Tags: java, javascript, html, spring-boot

I have a GET and a POST method that I want to control which one to use. They are the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
        return "greeting";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", greeting);
        return "result";
    }
```

The GET method starts an HTML file greetings.html and the POST method starts result.html.
As you can see they both have the same path (/Greeting).

In another HTML file I want to be able to link to /greetings but I want to be able to choose either the GET or the POST method. Is that possible?

This code is from another html file where I want to link to either the GET or the POST method:

```
<a href="/greeting">Go to greetings.html </a> 
<a href="/greeting">Go to result.html</a>
```

How can these links for the first to link to the GET method and the second to the POST method while keeping them on the same url?

Comment: You can't use `href` for `POST`, you'll have to submit a form or call a JS/jQuery function for that.

Comment: I guess you could do this using some scriping. I've added javascript for you.

Comment: A couple of forms with one button each and setting the method parameter would also do the trick, although this isn't exactly "linking".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second line, do

```
<form action='./greetings' method='post'><INPUT TYPE='submit' name='' value='Goto result.html'/></form>
```

Just please note that the second line appears as a button, not a hyperlink.

Comment: If you set something within the name parameter, (I know php can) check the input value with $_POST[''] (I don't know the ASP.NET equivalent.)